# Swift to get result of array values from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

My scenario i have four labels in a view, I need to get result of marks value and assign to that labels.If I received only one index within array I need to call some other function. I am using old method JSON not codable and thirdparty lib. Please provide some solution.

Below, my response

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "status_code": 200,
    "result": [
        "100 marks",
        "30 marks",
        "40 marks",
        "70 marks"
    ]
}
```

Below code I am using

```
if (status_code != 200) {
    print("ERROR:\(String(describing: status_code))")
} else {
    let results = result["result"]  as? String
    print("Marks:\(results ?? "")")

    // Call confirmation alert
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.one_label.text! = ""
        self.two_label.text! = ""
        self.three_label.text! = ""
        self.four_label.text! = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swift 4? If so, it's easy to add a single `Decodable` object just to handle this case. You don't need to remove any old code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result has [String] so please

Replace

```
let results = result["result"]  as? String
```

to

```
   if let results = result["result"]  as? [String], results.count >= 4 {

    self.one_label.text! = results[0] ?? ""
    self.two_label.text! = results[1] ?? ""
    self.three_label.text! = results[2] ?? ""
    self.four_label.text! = results[3] ?? ""

    } else {
        // Call your function here
    }
```

Comment: if I do this I can only print like print("Marks:\(results ?? [""])") @Jogendar Choudhary. How to assign each index value to that four labels and need to validate index value one.

Comment: You please check updated answer or you can use if-let

Comment: @iosdev: then remove where condition

Comment: @iosdev: I have added where condition in for loop, have you checked this, WIth this condition this for loop will itrate only 4 time, So if you have more then field or index then remove this condition or increase condtion 4 to more

Comment: @iosdev Is't working for you, or need to show you more ways to do that, You have many options like if-let , guard, codable.. I can also give you example so let me know that your requirment fullfill with this answer or not?

Comment: @iosdev: Please check

Comment: Wow this is I expected. Great. thank you I will check and mark it

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect part of your code is: you are trying to cast `result["result"]` as a singular `String`, which is not! it is an *array* of strings. So what you should do is:

```
if let results = result["result"]  as? [String] {
    print(results[0]) // first mark in the array (100 marks)
}
```

**Furthermore:**

At this point, I would recommend to follow the approach of *templating* the data instead of dealing with dictionaries. Since have a valid Json, you can achieve it easily with [`Docadable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol, Example:

```
let json = """
{
"status": 1,
"status_code": 200,
"result": [
"100 marks",
"30 marks",
"40 marks",
"70 marks"
]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct Result: Decodable {
    var status: Int
    var statusCode: Int
    var result: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case statusCode = "status_code"
        case result
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let resultObject = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: json!)
print(resultObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result in json is array. So you need to cast it to array.

```
let results = result["result"]  as? [String]
        print("Marks:\(results ?? "")")
```

Comment: thank you. But how to get separate index and assign to label. @Azat

Comment: You can access with results[0].